# Vuetify old style

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm pretty new to Vue/Vuetify, I've tried using the vuetify `v-text-field` tag with `outline` prop.

Why the label is like in the image?

Also the font seems not to be the Vuetify one.

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your *App.vue* in `<v-app>`.  Among other things, it wraps the app in the `v-application` class which a lot of styles use as part of their selector.  From the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/):

> The `v-app` component is REQUIRED for all applications. This is the mount point for many of Vuetify’s components and functionality and ensures that it propagates the default application variant (dark/light) to children components and also ensures proper cross-browser support for certain click events in browsers like Safari. v-app should only be rendered within your application ONCE.